# Entity Framework complex query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i'm trying to learn Entity Framework and I need some help to build my query.
I have a Post class like this :

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostID {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public PostStatus Status {get;set;}
    public IList<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

I also have a Comment class :

```
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public CommentStatus Status {get;set;}
}
```

What I want is to retrieve all Article with Status == PostStatus.Published, including Comment with Status == CommentStatus.Published.

As you understand, I want to display in a blog all published article with their published comment.

I retrieve all published article with all comments, but I only want to get their published comment, not pending ones.

```
var result = from art in context.Posts.Include("Comments")
             where art.Status == PostStatus.Published
             select art;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what is the issue? exception? by default EF does not support enums. Are you able to use PostStatus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and using your answers, I found that the good way to go is :

```
context.Posts.Where(p=> p.InternalStatus == (int)PostStatus.Published).ToList()
    .Select(item =>
                    new Post
                        {
                            PostID = item.PostID,
                            Title = item.Title,
                            Author = item.Author,
                            Content = item.Content,
                            DateCreation = item.DateCreation,
                            Status = item.Status,
                            Comments =
                                item.Comments.Where(
                                    comment => comment.InternalStatus == (int) CommentStatus.Approved).ToList()
                        }).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

well you need to create a new object list with it.
Something like this

```
var result = from art in context.Posts.Include("Comments").ToList()
             where art.Status == PostStatus.Published
             select new Post { PostID=art.PostID, Title=art.Title, Content=art.Content, Status=art.Status, Comments=art.Comment.Select(comment => comment.Status == CommentStatus.Published).ToList()};
```

Comment: I try this but I get the following error : The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 0):

Here how to select only Published posts with **at least one** Published comment:

```
var result = from p in context.Posts
             .Include("Comments")
             from c in p.Comments
             where p.Status == PostStatus.Published &&
                   c.Status == CommentStatus.Published
             select new Post {
                      PostID = p.PostID, 
                      // ... other members of Post
                      Comments = p.Comments
                             .Where(c2 => c2.Status == CommentStatus.Published).ToList()
                    };
```